# How to start a python file while Windows starts?

Tags: python, windows

I have a python file and I am running the file.

If Windows is shutdown and booted up again, how I can run that file every time Windows starts?

Answer (score 81):

Depending on what the script is doing, you may:

1. package it into a service, that should then be installed
2. add it to the windows registry (HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run)
3. add a shortcut to it to the startup folder of start menu - its location may change with OS version, but installers always have some instruction to put a shortcut into that folder
4. use windows' task scheduler, and then you can set the task on several kind of events, including logon and on startup.

The actual solution depends on your needs, and what the script is actually doing.
Some notes on the differences:

- Solution #1 starts the script with the computer, while solution #2 and #3 start it when the user who installed it logs in.
- It is also worth to note that #1 always start the script, while #2 and #3 will start the script only on a specific user (I think that if you use the default user then it will start on everyone, but I am not sure of the details).
- Solution #2 is a bit more "hidden" to the user, while solution #3 leaves much more control to the user in terms of disabling the automatic start.
- Finally, solution #1 requires administrative rights, while the other two may be done by any user.
- Solution #4 is something I discovered lately, and is very straightforward. The only problem I have noticed is that the python script will cause a small command window to appear.

As you can see, it all boils down to what you want to do; for instance, if it is something for your purposes only, I would simply drag it into startup folder.

**In any case, lately I am leaning on solution #4, as the quickest and most straightforward approach.**

Comment: FYI:  If you use pythonw.exe instead of python.exe to start your script, it shouldn't show the command window.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your help! Currently on pycharm I start one script with "python -m binance_trade_bot" and the other script with "python -m btb_manager_telegram -t XXXXX -c YYYYY" after opening each script manually. How could I apply that? :-)

Answer (score 27):

you can simply add the following code to your script. Nevertheless, this works only on windows!:

```
import getpass
import os
USER_NAME = getpass.getuser()


def add_to_startup(file_path=""):
    if file_path == "":
        file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    bat_path = r'C:\Users\%s\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup' % USER_NAME
    with open(bat_path + '\\' + "open.bat", "w+") as bat_file:
        bat_file.write(r'start "" "%s"' % file_path)
```

this function will create a bat file in the startup folder that will run your script.

the `file_path` is the path to the file that you would like to run when your computer opens.

you can leave it blank in order to add the running script to startup.

Comment: Why is there a `""` after `start`. I thought it had to be around the `%s` to handle spaces but when I tried that, it didn't work (just opened a command prompt)

Comment: There is one error ,It is in line 2 of function add_to_startup

Comment: os.path.dirname returns the folder's path rather than including the file's path but this can easily be fixed

Comment: @frakman1  the empty quotes after the start are there since the first parameter of the command "start" is the window's title - in this case there will be no title owing to the fact that the quotes are empty. Hence, if you remove the quotes the result will be start file_path. which will result in a cmd window with the title of file_path

Comment: only runs on login, not windows startup

Comment: it should be bat_file.write(r'start "" "%s"' % file_path)

Answer (score 20):

- click **Win+R**
- type **shell:startup**
- drag and drop your python file `my_script.py`

  - if you don't need the console:
    change extension from `my_script.py` to `my_script.pyw`
  - else:
    create `run_my_script.cmd` with content: `python path\to\your\my_script.py`

Comment: Dropping on it the file shortcut doesn't work, any idea about it?

Comment: @JinSnow Instead of a shortcut, try using the cmd file. In the cmd file, write "python [path to your python file]" on the first line. https://youtube.com/shorts/e0eTok8oZxw

Comment: Thanks, good idea! (I solved it by simply deleting the startup folder and creating a new one: https://superuser.com/a/1748854/235752  )

Answer (score 10):

Haven't tested this, but I'd create a batch file that contains "python yourfile.py" and put that in the autostart folder.

On Windows 7 you can find it here:

```
%APPDATA%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Comment: Run(WinKey + R) -> `shell:common startup`

Comment: only runs on login, not windows startup

Answer (score 10):

In the following startup directory (at least this path exists on Windows XP):

```
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

put a shortcut to your python program. It should be executed every time your system starts up.

Comment: i want to do that from command line and window 7 does not give permission to write.

Comment: @sam: I don't know what's the startup folder path in Windows 7. What I gave as an example is startup folder for all users. There should exist one for each user, and you can put the shortcut there. The shortcut can be a simple `bat` file with contents `python path_to_your_python_program.py`

Comment: only runs on login, not windows startup

Answer (score 6):

You can put run_script.cmd in

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Content of run_script.cmd

```
python path\to\your\script.py
```

Comment: Isn't this only ran at login?

Comment: only runs on login, not windows startup

Answer (score 3):

```
import winreg

def set_autostart_registry(app_name, key_data=None, autostart: bool = True) -> bool:
    """
    Create/update/delete Windows autostart registry key

    ! Windows ONLY
    ! If the function fails, OSError is raised.

    :param app_name:    A string containing the name of the application name
    :param key_data:    A string that specifies the application path.
    :param autostart:   True - create/update autostart key / False - delete autostart key
    :return:            True - Success / False - Error, app name dont exist
    """

    with winreg.OpenKey(
            key=winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
            sub_key=r'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run',
            reserved=0,
            access=winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS,
    ) as key:
        try:
            if autostart:
                winreg.SetValueEx(key, app_name, 0, winreg.REG_SZ, key_data)
            else:
                winreg.DeleteValue(key, app_name)
        except OSError:
            return False
    return True


def check_autostart_registry(value_name):
    """
    Check Windows autostart registry status

    ! Windows ONLY
    ! If the function fails, OSError is raised.

    :param value_name:  A string containing the name of the application name
    :return: True - Exist / False - Not exist
    """

    with winreg.OpenKey(
            key=winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
            sub_key=r'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run',
            reserved=0,
            access=winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS,
    ) as key:
        idx = 0
        while idx < 1_000:     # Max 1.000 values
            try:
                key_name, _, _ = winreg.EnumValue(key, idx)
                if key_name == value_name:
                    return True
                idx += 1
            except OSError:
                break
    return False
```

Create autostart:

`set_autostart_registry('App name', r'C:\test\x.exe')`

Update autostart:

`set_autostart_registry('App name', r'C:\test\y.exe')`

Delete autostart:

`set_autostart_registry('App name', autostart=False)`

Check autostart:

`if check_autostart_registry('App name'):`

Answer (score 1):

try adding an entry to "HKLM/SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce" .
Right click ->new -> string value -> add file path

Comment: What is difference between Run and RunOnce?

Comment: @Santosh Kumar By default, the values of RunOnce registry keys are deleted immediate before running on the command line. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an exe file, I use pyinstaller "yourCode.py"
2. Add the execution file to your registry key:
   https://cmatskas.com/configure-a-runonce-task-on-windows/

Answer (score 0):

Above mentioned all the methods did not worked I tried them all , I will tell you more simpler solution and alternative of windows task scheduler

Create a .bat file with content 
"ADDRESS OF YOUR PROJECT INTERPRETER" "ADDRESS OF YOUR PYTHON SCRIPT WITH SCRIPT NAME"

Store this bat file into the window startup folder(by default hidden)
FYI: to find window startup folder 
press **windos+r** then 
type **shell:startup** -- it will directly take you to the startup folder

copy the bat file there with following 2 address in the same format ,
then simply restart the system or shut down and boot up.

The code will automatically run within 20 seconds of opening.

Thank me later

Comment: only runs on login, not windows startup

Comment: Your will have to put the bat file in the startup folder , windows automatically start the application or code whatever is inside the startup folder .

Comment: Nope, doesn't work if the machine has a login password

Comment: See , I am Using this method on daily basis , I have created a assistant which automatically opens when my windows boot up and also my machine have login password, might be issue with the bat file (address of project interpreter or code ).

Answer (score 0):

```py
import shutil
from os import path
import getpass
USER_NAME = getpass.getuser()
source_path = "hi.txt"
    
if path.exists(source_path):
    destination_path = "C://Users//%s//AppData//Roaming//Microsoft//Windows//Start Menu//Programs//Startup" % USER_NAME
    new_location = shutil.copy(source_path, destination_path)
    print("% s перемещен в указанное место,% s" % (source_path , new_location))
    print(destination_path)
else :
    print ("Файл не существует.")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).