# How to run a python code at the login window?

Tags: python

I am working on a project and want that a python code to run automatically, as soon as the user encounters the login window showing the different account. Can someone please help me out with how to run a python code at the login window. I am working on python 3.1 and windows 7.

Comment: This is unlikely to be possible, as the Windows logon screen is on a secure desktop designed to run nothing but `winlogon`. Any workarounds will have to be extremely low-level and a high security risk - not something Python should (or can?) be used for: https://code.google.com/p/maestro/wiki/WinlogonDesktop

Answer (score 0):

[Somewhat related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438020/how-to-start-a-python-file-while-window-starts) and a solution.

Basically, if you want the script to show up something exactly at the time the log-in window is displayed, then you may want to go the service way.

In case you want the script to execute after the user logs in then, you can place a BAT file within the start-up programs list in Windows 7. This BAT file will invoke the python interpretor and execute the script.