# Windows 10 run python program in startup

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, startup, apscheduler

I have written a python program that periodically runs with ApScheduler package. The .pyw file runs in the background, but when I restart the PC the program doesn't continue running.

What can I do to run a code automatically in startup a windows 10 pc?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start a python file while Windows starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438020/how-to-start-a-python-file-while-windows-starts)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should consider putting your python file to the Startup folder.

Click **Win+R** at the same time on your keyboard
Type *shell:startup*
Drag and drop your python file onto the folder that opened.

Note: I reccomend to put a *shortcut* of your python file for easier editing.