# How to run the python script in background?

Tags: python, windows, background-process

What I want to achieve is that I want to make sure that the script starts running on it's own in the background as the system starts and alerts at some specific point in the code. Now I was thinking of adding the script to the 'startup' folder of windows, but how do I make sure that it runs in background and is there any other method other than the 'startup folder'.

```
#some random code
....
if value==2:
    alert()
...
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is not about Python per se, but rather on how to startup a script on Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start a python file while Windows starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438020/how-to-start-a-python-file-while-windows-starts)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you run a Python script as a service in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/how-do-you-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows)