# Starting a python file when a computer starts

Tags: python, windows-10, startup

I am trying to run a `python` file when my `Windows 10` computer starts up. I've already coded the file. It asks for a password and if its incorrect, it shutdown the computer. If the password is correct, it ends the file and lets the user to continue.

I've looked around but all i can see is how to do it with batch files or solutions to do it when a user logged in, im the only one that uses my machine and there is only 1 user

I've heard something about searching for a 'startup' folder but cant find it. Any ideas?

P.s if you know how to get to the start up folder that could help as well

Comment: out of record.. Im curious, why You want to check Yourself ? :)

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438020/how-to-start-a-python-file-while-windows-starts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your python file in the Startup folder. The folder is located at

```
C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

**Make sure you have enabled [*Show hidden files*](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14201/windows-show-hidden-files).** The `AppData` folder is a hidden folder so you won't find it if you don't enable it.

Comment: Its running it when i login instead of when my computer starts

Comment: @Jo-TechGames This is the only way. You cannot open a file as long as the user is not logged in.

Comment: Is there no way to put it in the boot loader?

Comment: @Jo-TechGames The only way to run a python file is to be logged in on the platform

Comment: What if i make a bat?

Comment: @Jo-TechGames There is no way to run or open anything when the user is not logged in (in short you cannot open any file when the user has to login to unlock the windows)