# Getting the program into Windows startup

Tags: python, startup

Is there a way to make this function directly in the script so that when the program starts, it automatically goes to startup 
C: \ Users \% NaMe% \ AppData \ Roaming \ Microsoft \ Windows \ Start Menu \ Programs \ Startup.

Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start a python file while Windows starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438020/how-to-start-a-python-file-while-windows-starts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if this is your own PC you can physically go to that location and paste it and from task manager make it run on startup.

But second, if you want to do on a different script I would recommend making an external python file with code something like this.

```
import winreg as reg  
import os              

def AddToRegistry(): 

    # in python __file__ is the instant of 
    # file path where it was executed  
    # so if it was executed from desktop, 
    # then __file__ will be  
    # c:\users\current_user\desktop 
    pth = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) 

    # name of the python file with extension 
    s_name="mYscript.py"     

    # joins the file name to end of path address 
    address=os.join(pth,s_name)  

    # key we want to change is HKEY_CURRENT_USER  
    # key value is Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run 
    key = HKEY_CURRENT_USER 
    key_value = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"

    # open the key to make changes to 
    open = reg.OpenKey(key,key_value,0,reg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS) 

    # modifiy the opened key 
    reg.SetValueEx(open,"any_name",0,reg.REG_SZ,address) 

    # now close the opened key 
    reg.CloseKey(open) 

if __name__=="__main__": 
    AddToRegistry()
```

You can also add this to the same file, but it may result in unforeseen circumstances. You can [click](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/autorun-a-python-script-on-windows-startup/) here or go to the below-mentioned link to learn more and add some other options.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/autorun-a-python-script-on-windows-startup/