# How to automate a program to start automatically when my windows 10 PC starts

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tkinter, automation

I want to make a Python 3 tkinter program start when my PC starts. For example, My tkinter window that i programmed must start after I log in. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438020/how-to-start-a-python-file-while-windows-starts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.Create a batch file to start your application.**

Open Notepad and create batch file based on the following template.

```
"Path where your Python exe is stored\python.exe" "Path where your Python script is stored\script name.py"
pause
```

Save the file as a bat file (Ex: script.bat) and create a shortcut.

**2. Put the batch file in startup folder**

1. Press the Start button and type Run and press enter
2. Type `shell:startup` in run window and press enter
3. Past the bath file shortcut in the window opened.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Thanks for your suggestion. I've added examples