# How to run python script on start up of pc but only once in day?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, startupscript

I have created a python script which do birthday wish to a person automatically when birthdate is arrive. I added this script on window start up but it run every time when i start my pc and do birthday wish to person also. I want to run that script only once a day. What should i do?

Comment: Is using an task scheduler an option?

Comment: You can do that by creating a service file using `systemctl` utility.

Comment: Use your os scheduler to run the script instead.

Comment: After sending the greeting, make a note in a file.  Before sending the greeting, check the file to see if you've already sent the greeting.

Comment: I think task schedular work only on perticular time but i want to make it work like any time when pc start but only once.

Comment: @SmitParmar, I suggest following this tutorial: https://tecadmin.net/setup-autorun-python-script-using-systemd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this at the start of the file:

```
import datetime

actualday = datetime.datetime.today().day  # get the actual day 
actualmonth = datetime.datetime.today().month  # get the actual month 

bday = 1  # day of birthday
bmonth = 1  # month of birthday

if actualday == bday and actualmonth == bmonth :
    # code
```

it should finish the process if the dates aren't equal

Answer (score 0):

You can run this program when the system boot [How to start a python file while Windows starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438020/how-to-start-a-python-file-while-windows-starts)

And after that, you need check the time of when the system started like:

```
import datetime
dayToday = datetime.datetime.today().day
monthToday = datetime.datetime.today().month

birthdayDay = 1
birthdayMonth = 10

if dayToday == birthdayDay and monthToday == birthdayMonth:
      print "HPBD"
```