# running a python script from startup to shutdown

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, keylogger

I am using python 3. On windows 7.
I recently made a **python keylogger**. It saves the keylogs in a text file as i type and upon pressing WIDOWS Key it sends the text from the textfile to my gmail account using smtplib.
I have to manually start the python file and it gets quite boring!

What my question is that is there any way to **run that keylogger script on startup** (without manually putting it in the startup folder -- because i want the script to do everything itself), and then to quickly **close the script as soon as the user presses the shutdown button** (and delay the shutdown time somehow).
The reason i want this is because i belive that a keylogger must be hidden from the user not to include that it must be hidden from the antivirus ;)

i have tested this with **python task scheduler** but it only takes time parameters (i.e. from 5:00 to 7:00) not the startup and shutdown time.

If i am to include more information on this topic that you need to solve this question i will gladly help you!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start a python file while Windows starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438020/how-to-start-a-python-file-while-windows-starts)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, but this is not what i am looking for i am looking for a script that runs at startup and closes itself on shutdown

Comment: Have you tried task scheduler built in windows?

Comment: no id did not use it because it is not kind of hidden from the user

Comment: I think he wants to use shutdown as a trigger to do some processing before shutting down. Is it @HuzefaUsama?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i want @pagalprogrammer

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA it is not true! look here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn789190(v=ws.11)