# Create an App that cmd ''ipconfig/flushdns'' command each certain time using Python?

Tags: python, ipconfig

I'd like to create short app that runs with windows start and execute flashdns for example every 1h.
Maybe compile to into exe file.

I know that start of this will be:

```
import os
os.system('ipconfig/flushdns')
```

but i didn't find answer how this function will look like and how to compile it and run it with windows.

Answer (score 0):

This guide should get you covered, it shows how you can run and execute commands in cmd: https://datatofish.com/command-prompt-python/

Comment: done. do you know how to run it at windows startup in powershell or cmd?

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438020/how-to-start-a-python-file-while-windows-starts

Comment: os.system('cmd /k "ipconfig/flushdns"')
    threading.Timer(1.0, flushdns).start()

Comment: but script closes after execute

Answer (score 0):

To run your command on a schedule, you can use an infinite `while` loop and `time.sleep`, which takes a number of seconds to delay thread execution by:

```
import time
import os

while True:
    os.system("ipconfig /flushdns")
    time.sleep(3600)
```

If you are doing other things in this program, you may want to run this loop in a [thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html).

To "compile" your program into a Windows executable file, you can use [py2exe](https://www.py2exe.org/) or [cx_Freeze](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (just some examples, there are certainly more tools available that have this functionality).

Answer (score 0):

Big Thanks to:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/9359583/kremklatt

I used links:

[How to start a python file while Windows starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438020/how-to-start-a-python-file-while-windows-starts)
https://datatofish.com/command-prompt-python/

And Final Script:

```
import os
import threading

def flushdns():
    threading.Timer(60.0, flushdns).start()  # repeat every 60 seconds
    os.system('cmd /k "ipconfig/flushdns"')

flushdns()
```

This Community is Epic xD

https://github.com/perdubaro/DnsFlusher

any feedback welcome :)