# Making python code run at startup in windows

Tags: python, windows

I want to make a python code to run persistently in windows.
I am trying to make a backdoor in python , and i want to add persistence to it.

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438020/how-to-start-a-python-file-while-windows-starts

Comment: Use [scheduler] (https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and create a .bat file with cmd like "python C:path_to_script/myscript.py" and put this file inside startup file (win+r and type shell:startup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a batch file and store it in startup folder to achieve such a thing,just make a batch file named `whatever.bat`.then write the following code in it.

```
@echo off
python pathtoyourpyfile\app.py
```

after making the batch file,navigate to `C:\Users\[your username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`  and paste the batch-file here .now every time when your pc will start thhis batch-file will execute and call your python script.

Comment: instead of navigating u can win+r and type shell:startup

Comment: yeah a good snippet thnx

Answer (score 0):

if can simply add the following code to your script. , this only works on windows!:

```
import getpass
import os
USER_NAME = getpass.getuser()


def add_to_startup(file_path=""):
    if file_path == "":
        file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    bat_path = r'C:\Users\%s\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup' % USER_NAME
    with open(bat_path + '\\' + "open.bat", "w+") as bat_file:
        bat_file.write(r'start "" %s' % file_path)
```