# Why does the file execution fail by starting the system?

Tags: python, windows, exe, telegram-bot

1. I have the following *python file*, which simply:

   - connects to ****telegram**** bot
   - waits for command ("\s" or "\screenshot") and **then sends time + screenshot**
2. Then I make the **Windows-Executable file** with:

   `pyinstaller "filename.py" -w -F`

   *w and F* means here, that it is a *background process and should be
   compiled to one file.*

   If I start it on Windows machine everything is okey: I do not see
   any windows and can comunicate with desktop per telegram bot.
3. The problem appears then **I move the file to the StartUp Windows
   Folder:**

   `C:\Users\Elliot\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp`
4. I *restart then my windows system* and see the following window error:

   **Failed to execute script filename.py**

   Thefore the bot does not react on my messages and no process appear in the task manager.

What am I doing wrong? I appreciate any help!

Python code:

```
import telebot
import pyautogui
import os
from datetime import datetime

#this is the initialization command
bot = telebot.TeleBot("this-are-numbers-to-connect-to-bote")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['s', 'screenshot'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "[+] Hello, i am sending you the screenshot")
    uphoto = pyautogui.screenshot("pic.jpg")
    today = datetime.now()
    today = "Date: "+str(today)
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, uphoto, today)
    os.remove("pic.jpg")
#start listening
bot.polling()
```

Comment: Duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438020/how-to-start-a-python-file-while-windows-starts

Comment: I tried with the shortcut and the message is still appearing ...

Comment: You said that you are using pyinstaller to create an exe but then you said that there is error with "filename.py" - there's something not right here. Another issue with autostart - offten network is not available right now and you have to wait a couple of seconds or your script may fail.