# Run PyCharm with command on PC Startup

Tags: python, pycharm, command, startup

I am using PyCharm in two instances for crypto-trading. Currently when my computer starts up, I would have to open both projects on PyCharm manually and enter two different commands manually.

Is there a way to run these projects with the commands needed automatically right after starting my computer?

Answer (score 1):

A better way to start your bot on startup is to add your python script or something in a startup or run your python script as a service.

[Check out this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438020/how-to-start-a-python-file-while-windows-starts)

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your reply! Currently I start one script with "python -m binance_trade_bot" and the other script with "python -m btb_manager_telegram -t XXXXX -c YYYYY" after opening each script manually. How could I apply that? :-)

Comment: import os
os.system(f"start cmd /K python -m binance_trade_bot")

Comment: Thanks man but I still don't get it :-) What must I do with this snippet and where?