# How to run flask app automatically during windows boot?

Tags: python, windows, flask, automation, windows-services

How to run `flask app` automatically during windows boot?

I have a simple python app

```
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    # Login Service
    logging.debug("hello world")
    return "Hello World!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

`python app.py` runs a `web app` on http://localhost:5000

I want to start the same automatically during the windows boot.

I am new to python + flask + Windows..

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438020/how-to-start-a-python-file-while-windows-starts . The main difficulty I can see you running into is making sure the current working directory is the directory of the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a file run_app.bat in your project directory

```
@echo off
cls

:top
echo.
echo Starting...
echo.

python app.py
```

and put a shortcut of this file in windows startup folder :
`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp`

Comment: How to run it in the background?