# Is it possible to autoboot my python program when i start my laptop from shutdown, but only once a day?

Tags: python

I wanna auto boot my python script every day when i start my laptop from shut down, but only once a day. Is it possible?

Comment: Of course.  Which operating system?

Comment: for windows you can check this link [How to Schedule Python Script using Windows Scheduler](https://datatofish.com/python-script-windows-scheduler/)

Comment: This is not a Python question, but a question about whatever operating system you are using, and thus probably not really a suitable question for StackOverflow. Consider asking https://superuser.com

Comment: Is this helpful? => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438020/how-to-start-a-python-file-while-windows-starts

Comment: For the first commenter l, im using windows. For the 4 th, i looked at it but it was for every login, not startip

Comment: For the second comment, it is using task scheduler which only works if the system is on at a fixed time. I want it in a range of time or just once a day without time limits