# Running a python script from startup. (Windows and RPI os)

Tags: python, linux, windows, startup, raspberry-pi4

I have some Python scripts, and I want them to be started at system startup.
How can I do this?
By startup apps?
Do I need to export the script as an exe and then add it to the startup applications?
What about the raspberry pi?
Or another Linux?

(There are some posts about this, but none of them answer exactly my question)

Comment: Which OS you want to do this?

Comment: Both windows and rpios

Comment: The answers might vary greatly between setting it up on windows, or pi, or linux. I suggest you to narrow your focus

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues But i need it for windows rpi linux, becouse i wan't to cennect them on start using python

Comment: There is (obviously?) not one way but it depends on the system. Don't cram multiple questions into one. Do some reasonable research as well.

Comment: For [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438020/how-to-start-a-python-file-while-windows-starts), for [pi](https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/), for [linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/634410/start-python-script-at-startup)

Answer (score 1):

As for the rpios, just add the command you want to run at startup to the file `/etc/rc.local`. It will be run on startup.

Comment: TY i will check that later.